# onTouchListener togglebutton, ignores first press?

Tags: android

I have a togglebutton that should run code when I press it down and more code when I let go. However the first time I press and let go nothing happens. Every other time it is fine, why is this? I can see the method only runs the first time when I let go of the button (it does not trigger any onTouch part of the method though), how can I get around this, and have it work for the first press?

```
public void pushtotalk3(final View view) {
    ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(true);
    ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //if more than one call, change this code
            int callId = 0;
            for (SipCallSession callInfo : callsInfo) {
                callId = callInfo.getCallId();
                Log.e(TAG, "" + callInfo.getCallId());
            }
            final int id = callId;
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {  //press
                    ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                    ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(true);
                    OnDtmf(id, 17, 10);
                    OnDtmf(id, 16, 9);
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: { //release
                    ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                    ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false);
                    OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                    OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                    return true;
                }
                default: return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: the xml for the button:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/PTT_button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/ptt5" 
        android:onClick="pushtotalk5"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:textOn="Push To Talk On"
        android:textOff="Push To Talk Off"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_lightblue_glossy"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
```

EDIT: hardware problem, can't test solutions atm.

Comment: Does the onTouch method even get called the first time or does it skip the whole method? Also is there a reason you are setting your togglebutton this was and not using the normal findViewById?

Comment: I think it skips the whole touch method but i will test further. I stopped the normal way because there was a lot of complications and this way was working much easier.

Comment: when i was using the normal method I had setcontent to a different xml file than the one with some of my layout, this was causing a nullpointer exception. This way was working immediately apart from this.

Comment: confirmed the ontouch method does not get ran the first click and is fine for the rest of them

Comment: The button wouldn't happen to have `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` as part of its layout, would it?

Comment: @blahdiblah I'll add in the button now, it doesnt have that

Comment: **Don't add that.**  That was a potential cause of the problem, not a solution.

Comment: @blahdiblah Hey, i figured that out very quickly :)

Comment: Is the problem resolved? Can you tell me where is the `pushtotalk3` method.. in the activity which contains the toggle button? Also post updated code if you have made changes..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare It is not resolved, it is in an activity, the togglebutton is not defined in this contentView. No changes.

Comment: Ok. If it is not the the content view.. where it is? How does it become visible in the activity? Can you tell me so I can understand the flow..

Comment: It is inflated by some other code, i don't really follow how: here is the source https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/src/?r=2170#src%2Fcom%2Fcsipsimple%2Fui%2Fincall I can set the listener in the other class incallcard.java fine but I do not know how to initialise the "service" object, this is why I am trying to call the method in incallactivity, as service is alaready initialised and I can use it.

Comment: I am only editing this code you see, I did not write it.

Comment: My answer should resolve your problems. You should have posted the link earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `in_call_card.xml` contains the `ToggleButton`. According to the link of the source code, the `in_call_card.xml` is inflated in `InCallCard.java`. `InCallCard` is  a custom view defined by the application.

In order to attach the listener, you need to see where the `InCallCard` is being used within the `InCallActivity`. And you find it in the `getView` method (near the end of the file).

Based on the above observations, your problem can be resolved by:

1) find the button within the `InCallCard` view

2) Attach the `OnTouchListener` programatically as I have shown below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = new InCallCard(InCallActivity.this, null);
    }

    if(convertView instanceof InCallCard) {
        InCallCard vc = (InCallCard) convertView;
        vc.setOnTriggerListener(InCallActivity.this);

        // set the touch listener here.. 
        // (1) get the button within the InCallCard view (vc)
        // (2) set the onTouchListener
        final View view = vc.findViewById(R.id.PTT_button5);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //if more than one call, change this code
                int callId = 0;
                for (SipCallSession callInfo : callsInfo) {
                    callId = callInfo.getCallId();
                    Log.e(TAG, "" + callInfo.getCallId());
                }
                final int id = callId;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {  //press
                        ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                        ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(true);
                        OnDtmf(id, 17, 10);
                        OnDtmf(id, 16, 9);
                        return true;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: { //release
                        ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                        ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false);
                        OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                        OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                        return true;
                    }
                    default: return false;
                }
            }
        });

        SipCallSession session = (SipCallSession) getItem(position);
        vc.setCallState(session);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Note: This is not the most efficient way of doing things (as we do a `findViewById`), but will sure resolve your problems. If you want to improve, read about the `ViewHolder` pattern in android and use  it here.

Also, you should have posted the `src` code link earlier. Everyone here was giving the right answer but no one was sure of what your particular scenario was.

Comment: Great answer along with your other one, thank you. Sorry I did not post the code. you really helped me understand better, getView was the missing piece for me. I will try to implement your answer and look into ViewHolder if this is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use a gesture detector rather than `onTouch`:

```
private class CustomGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private boolean down = false;

    @Override   
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        down = true;
        doDownActions();
    }

    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        if (down) {
            down = false;
            doUpActions();
        }

        // The gesture has been used so return true. If you wish to pretend it hasn't
        // return false
        return true;
    }

    // Strictly you may also need to catch some of the other events to
    // guarantee correct termination of the sequence
}
```

Then, this listener needs to be created and added to the view:

```
// Create it.
final GestureDetector myGestureListener = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new CustomGestureListener());

// Set it up for use:
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        myGestureListener.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Pass it on to the system. Be cleverer about this if needed!
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});

// And put an onClick method it to force it to work (this shouldn't be necessary but
// it seems like sometimes it is)
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't know anything about GestureListener, I will give this a try and get back to you, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the toggle button would be better if you used the layout. Its easier for me at least

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View otherLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.toggle_layout, null);
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) otherLayout.findViewById(R.id.toggleID);
toggle.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           switch(event.getAction()) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 //your code
                 break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 // your code
                 break;
           }
           return false;
    }
});
```

Try that and let me know. I have the same thing for a button but I use onClick instead of onTouch.

Comment: You have to place that in onCreate don't you? The problem with that is my xml is not in the same xml file that setContentView(); calls.

Comment: So I have my togglebutton in in_call_card.xml, but onCreate references setContentView(R.layout.in_call_main); and I get a nullpointerexception

Comment: That is fine. I reference a different layout in mine. I have setContent(R.layout.main) and then I get the R.layout.window.

Comment: Ah i see, I think this was my missing piece, I did not know how to reference another layout

Comment: I have tried that now and while there are no errors, clicking the button doesnt call the code in the listener, it just changes the buttons toggle state!

Answer (score 1):

I just changed your logic a big and it works well for me. You can put your telephony related stuff back and test. And you don't need onClick listener because onTouch listener replaces it completely.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_touch);

    final View view = findViewById(R.id.PTT_button5);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {  //press
                    System.out.println("talk");
                    ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(true);
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: { //release
                    System.out.println("don't talk");
                    ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false);
                    return true;
                }
                default: return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am looking for the method solution to this, not the ` findViewById(R.id.PTT_button5);` method. Due to some reasons I can't do it this way. but thank you

Answer (score 1):

is happend because you are seeting listner when you clicked on your button so you have to set listner in onCreate just replace below code with your.

```
public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
          //setContetView
          //other intlization goes here

          view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //if more than one call, change this code
                int callId = 0;
                for (SipCallSession callInfo : callsInfo) {
                    callId = callInfo.getCallId();
                    Log.e(TAG, "" + callInfo.getCallId());
                }
                final int id = callId;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {  //press
                        ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                        ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(true);
                        OnDtmf(id, 17, 10);
                        OnDtmf(id, 16, 9);
                        return true;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: { //release
                        ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                        ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false);
                        OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                        OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                        return true;
                    }
                    default: return false;
                }
            }
        });

}




public void pushtotalk3(final View view) {
        ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(true);
        ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false);


}
```

Comment: If I do it this way view will cause an error, as it is passed in in the method, how else can I get it?

Comment: first tell me when pushtotalk3 method is called?

Comment: it is called when you press a button during a phone call. so I push the button and the code is ran, when I let go other code is ran.

Comment: ya then you can set the view.onTouchListener(this) before passing view to function.

Comment: if your view is more than one then your activity should implement onTouchListner interface and overrride all his method after that just register your listner like this way v1.setOnTouchListner(this),v2.setOntouchListner(this)...

Comment: there should be just one view, if I do `view.setOnTouchListener(this) I get `The method setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (InCallActivity)`. i will investigate

Comment: if you have just one view then just do as i mention in answer view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {.....  but before calling a pushtotalk3 function

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying but view is giving me an error when I try to do it, `the method setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (InCallActivity)`.`

Comment: ok just do this  ((ToggleButton) view).setOnTouchListner(new View.OnTouchListner){...} or togglebtn.setOntouchListner(new View.OnTouchListner){...}

Comment: I will try this thanks, I can't test this today due to hardware problems

Answer (score 1):

I like the beworker's answer, but if you can't you.

Your activity class can implement the OnTouchListener and into the method onTouch() and if the view is corrct handle the event otherwise not handle the event.

The method pushtotalk3() can be empty.

Example

```
class MyActivity implements OnTouchListener{
    // code ..
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(v.getId() != R.id.PTT_button5)
                return false;

        //if more than one call, change this code
        int callId = 0;
        for (SipCallSession callInfo : callsInfo) {
            callId = callInfo.getCallId();
            Log.e(TAG, "" + callInfo.getCallId());
        }
        final int id = callId;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {  //press
                ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_blue_glossy);
                ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(true);
                OnDtmf(id, 17, 10);
                OnDtmf(id, 16, 9);
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: { //release
                ((ToggleButton) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_lightblue_glossy);
                ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false);
                OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                OnDtmf(id, 18, 11);
                return true;
            }
            default: return false;
        }
    }

    public void pushtotalk3(final View view) {}
```

}

Now set the listener.There are two case.

Case layout inflated:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if(parent!=null)
        parent.setOnTouchListener(this);        
    return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```

case view created programmatically

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View myView = new MyView();

    setContentView(myView);
            myView.setOnTouchListener(this);

}
```

Comment: this may be because there is no initialisation of the listener in onCreate? The Pushtotalk method does get called but there is nothing in it.

Comment: Yes, set the listener with your root view.If you inflate the xml layout you can override the `onCreateView` method and set the listener to the parent view passed by parameter, otherwise use the view created programmatically into `onCreate`.