# findViewById in a different xml file?

Tags: android

I am editing csipsimple app and I have setContentView to this file, in_call_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/dropZones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout="@layout/in_call_drop_zones" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inCallContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <!--
                Can we do better than using two linear layouts here?
                The problem is that RelativeLayout doesn't allow to use weight and
                plays bad with hidden childs and above/below only support one id
            -->
            <!-- Grid for active calls -->

            <com.csipsimple.ui.incall.InCallInfoGrid
                android:id="@+id/activeCallsGrid"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:paddingBottom="4dip"
                android:paddingTop="4dip"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />

            <!-- Grid for held calls -->

            <com.csipsimple.ui.incall.InCallInfoGrid
                android:id="@+id/heldCallsGrid"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/in_call_held_background"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Answer slider/buttons -->

        <com.csipsimple.ui.incall.locker.InCallAnswerControls
            android:id="@+id/inCallAnswerControls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <!-- Wraps split action bar manually managed -->

        <com.csipsimple.ui.incall.InCallControls
            android:id="@+id/inCallControls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/incall_bottom_bar_bg" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.csipsimple.ui.incall.locker.ScreenLocker
        android:id="@+id/lockerOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#8000"
        android:visibility="gone" >

    </com.csipsimple.ui.incall.locker.ScreenLocker>



</RelativeLayout>
```

There is another layout file, in_call_card.xml; with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/call_card_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="2dip"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw" >

    <com.csipsimple.widgets.MaxScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/call_action_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty_description"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture_180_holo_light" /> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_name_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#9e808080"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >
  <!--     
            <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >



        <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
       --> 

        <com.csipsimple.widgets.MarqueeTextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_name_display_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <com.csipsimple.widgets.MarqueeTextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_name_sip_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name_display_name"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/elapsedTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/call_status_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name_bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:background="#c818617b"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:text="@string/call_state_calling"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/call_secure_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/call_status_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:background="#c8d4aa00" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/call_secure_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="2dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty_description"
            android:src="@drawable/stat_sys_vp_phone_call" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/call_secure_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/call_secure_icon"
            android:padding="2dip"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/call_action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/end_call_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout


        android:id="@+id/end_call_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:background="@drawable/end_call_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!--   android:onClick="pushtotalk3" -->
         <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/PTT_button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
            android:text="@string/ptt5" 
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:textOn="Push To Talk On"
            android:textOff="Push To Talk Off"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_lightblue_glossy"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />      

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/endButton"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:contentDescription="@string/done"
            android:minHeight="64dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_end_call" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

When I setContentView to the other xml file, I can still see elements from this file, I am not sure how this works. As in I can see the `PTT_button5` button etc, my problem is that if I want to set a listener on this button, how do I do it? If I try to reference it I get a Null Pointer Exception:

```
findViewById(R.id.PTT_button5).setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Is this because I have setContentView to a file that does not contain a reference to this button, so how do I get a reference to this button? I am also not sure how this works as in the button is displayed on screen without settingContentView to that file.

EDIT: as the button is on screen, can anybody see how it is done from the code?
https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/src/com/csipsimple/ui/incall/?r=2170

Comment: help me to understand. you call setContentView with the first xml and then with the second one?

Comment: Check if  com.csipsimple.ui.incall.InCallInfoGrid is inflating  in_call_card.xml somewhere in code.

Comment: @blackbelt apart from what you asked in comment. "I am also not sure how this works as in the button is displayed on screen without settingContentView to that file". this is confusing

Comment: @Brontok Can't see any inflation hmm, it must be inflated somewhere as the button shows ion the UI.

Comment: @Raghunandan What this means is the button I declare is displayed, but I have seen nothing that inflates it, so it must be done somewhere in the code. Perhaps some other file that in_call_main calls? here is teh code https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/src/com/csipsimple/ui/incall/?r=2170

Comment: @Paul Exactly , There is no other way two different UI is visible on a single screen.

Comment: can you see any inflation here? https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/src/com/csipsimple/ui/incall/?r=2170

Comment: @Paul `com.csipsimple.ui.incall.InCallInfoGrid` this is a custom view that is set to your layout xml

Comment: @Paul `com.csipsimple.ui.incall.locker.InCallAnswerControls` is added to your layout xml it's a custom class which extends relative layout and i guess your call controls are defined in the class `InCallAnswerControls` and that is what you see in the screen shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to understand the following basics:

**1)** `Activity` provides a window for you in which you can place your UI with `setContentView(View)`

In your case, this `View` (lets call it `contentView`) is inflated using `in_call_main.xml`

**2)** The `contentView` contains other views.

In your case, the `contentView` contains views, which are defined in the XML layout. This is the reason why they are shown when the activity starts. (If xml file is empty, you don't see anything)

**3** You can add and remove views from the `contentView`.

This means that, using code, we can create a new view (lets say `ToggleButton`) and add it to the `contentView`. This `ToggleButton` is now visible on the screen. (because it is a child of the `contentView`). Similarly, removing a child view will cause it to disappear.

**4)** Any view, (not just `contentView`) can be inflated (created) from a layout file.

In your case, `InCallCard` is a view, which is being inflated from the `in_call_card.xml`.

When the `getView()` method of the `CallsAdapter` is called.. a new instance of `InCallCard` (view) is created and returned. It is then attached to the `contentView` and therefor all the UI elements (views) inside the `InCallCard` (`in_call_card.xml`) are now visible on the screen. (Including the `ToggleButton` that has troubled you so much)

Therefore, if you try to access the `ToggleButton` from `onCreate()` it will be null. It has not been added to the `contentView` as yet. But if you do the same in the `getView` method, as I have explained in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19780986/827110). You will see that it is no more null, and you can attach listeners, change background etc..

Answer (score 0):

> Is this because I have setContentView to a file that does not contain
>   a reference to this button.

Yes. `findviewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout. So if you set the content of the layout to the activity, it looks for a view with the id mentioned in that layout. If not your initialization fails and you get `NullPointerException`.

You say

> I have setContentView to this file, in_call_main.xml

So

```
  setContentView(R.layout.in_call_main);
  findViewById(R.id.PTT_button5).setOnTouchListener(this);// gives NPE
  //in_call_main.xml does not have a toogle button with id button5
```

In `in_call_card.xml` you have

```
  <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/PTT_button5"
```

But if you have

```
  setContentView(R.layout.in_call_card);
  findViewById(R.id.PTT_button5).setOnTouchListener(this);// works
  // in_call_card.xml has a toogle button with id button5
```

> so how do I get a reference to this button?

You can't without inflating the layout.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I suspected, however somewhere in the code the layout must be inflated, as I can see the button correctly on screen. I just have no idea how this is done in the code. Somebody suggested I look at `com.csipsimple.ui.incall.InCallInfoGrid is inflating in_call_card.xml` it does not, but maybe some reference in   in_call_main.xml is making a call to inflate some of the code of in_call_card?

Comment: I tried inflating the layout and setting the content to in_call_card but this jsut changed the way the activity looked completely, yes my button worked but nothing else was the same.

Comment: yes i am confused as to how a button from a different layout is displayed on the screen without setting another layout to the current activity? does not make sense

Comment: I don not understand myself, for instance although I setCOntentView(in_call_main) the buttons I can see on screen come from in_call_card, such as endButton and the button I have defined.There are no buttons defined in in_call_main yet I see lots of buttons on screen...

Comment: @Paul can you post your code where you say the layout in inflated?

Comment: That is the problem, i don't know how the code is inflated at all from reading in_call_main but as you can see my button in in_call_card is clearly shown: http://i.imgur.com/p1I2Lgl.png I can see those two bottom buttons in in_call_card

Comment: All the code is here: https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/src/com/csipsimple/ui/incall/?r=2170

Comment: I am currently reading through in_call_main looking at files it references to see if they have anything got to do with inflating the buttons.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40189/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-paul)